# java language detection LangDetectException

Tags: java, language-detection

Working on language detection in java, i try to use langdetect library but i got this error when running **Exception in thread "main" com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.LangDetectException: need to load profiles**. Could someone help me to add profile? i don't know it can look like.

regards,

Comment: i try this part of code  Detector detector = DetectorFactory.create();
         detector.append(text);
         return detector.detect();

Comment: Read the "getting started" page for the library - http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/wiki/GettingStarted.  It shows you where to get the profiles from ...

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
  DetectorFactory.loadProfile("your/path/to/profiles");
```

Comment: ok. i don't have profile and don't know how it could look like. Could you send me  a profile example please? thanks a lot.

Comment: profiles are present in the profile folder.Which is present in the  downloaded langDetect zip folder.

Comment: If this fixes the issue, please mark the answer as solving. Remember, this is **not** a forum, it is a question-answer community.

Answer (score 0):

you can download the profile from: Profiles can be downloaded from : https://language-detection.googlecode.com/files/langdetect-09-13-2011.zip