# Cannot find the path of folder in the same directory location - Android studio

Tags: android, file, android-studio, directory, file-exists

I drop a folder called `profiles` in the same directory where my java files stored.

[image]

I tried to find the folder but get a not-found error.

```
String dir = getApplicationInfo().dataDir;
Log.d("dir", dir);
File folder = new File("/profiles"); // also tried File folder = new File(dir+"/profiles");
if (!folder.exists()) {
    Log.d("Not Found Dir", "Not Found Dir  ");
} else {
    Log.d("Found Dir", "Found Dir  " );
}
```

Print

```
D/dir: /data/user/0/com.pakhocheung.o
D/Not Found Dir: Not Found Dir
```

Then I tried to list all the files in that directory

```
String path = dir;
Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
File directory = new File(path);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
}
```

Print

```
D/Files: Path: /data/user/0/com.pakhocheung.o
D/Files: Size: 6
D/Files: FileName:cache
D/Files: FileName:code_cache
D/Files: FileName:lib
D/Files: FileName:shared_prefs
D/Files: FileName:app_Paas
D/Files: FileName:files
```

It seems I am in the wrong directory because I can't see those files. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've never seen like usage. Try to put your folder into assets or raw.

Comment: If I put the file in assets, how can I get that path?

Comment: `file:///android_asset/profiles/`

Comment: Any success? Any problems?

Comment: Not success yet. Trying. I just try ```String path = "file:///android_asset/"``` to see all files. I get a java.lang.NullPointerException error

Comment: Where did you put your assets folder?

Comment: it's path `src/main/assets`. Create it just inside `main`. Or read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706843/adding-an-assets-folder-in-android-studio

Comment: /Users/pakhocheung/Desktop/o/app/src/main/assets

Comment: I uploaded my answer try that . I think it helps you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160674/discussion-between-bek-and-pak-ho-cheung).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `assests` folder inside `main` folder. Put your `profiles` folder in `assets` folder. To read file names inside `profiles` folder use this code.

```
String[] list = null;
    try {
        list = getAssets().list("profiles");
        for (String file: list){
            Log.d(TAG, "file name "+ file.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

To read file from this folder use this.

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("profiles/example.txt");
```

Comment: If I can see all the files using ```getAssets().list("profiles")```, why ```File folder = new File("file:///android_asset/profiles/");``` shows not exist? Thanks for the help

Comment: You can use this path only for `url` `file:///android_asset/profiles/"`. for example you can use this in `WebView`.

Comment: What do you have in `profiles`? What do you want to do with them.

Comment: Oh I see. I need to call the path to load some data. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22934175/5737856

Comment: Argument should be ```File``` or ```String``` (the path). I also tried to convert the ```InputStream``` to ```File``` using this function. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11820891/5737856. But get a ```java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File[] java.io.File.listFiles()' on a null object reference error```. Anyways, thanks for the help. I need to take a rest. If I figure out later, I will vote your answer .Thanks.

Comment: You can't directly create file from assets folder. Read this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402757/8942811 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/15575813/8942811

Comment: Damn. Finally done with it using other method. Thanks